# transform the numbers to letters using php

Tags: php

I store the number `1 2 3 4` as the answer to multiple choice questions in MySQL database,

But I want to display them in `a b c d` on web page.

I'm using PHP, how can I transform the numbers to letters using PHP?

```
echo "
<h2>question</h2>
<p>".$row[0]."</p>
<h2>answer</h2>
<p>".$row[1]."</p>";
```

The `row[1]` is `{1,2,3,4}` now, I want it turn to `{A,B,C,D}`.

Can any one please have a look and tell me how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Hints: [chr](http://www.php.net/chr), an array lookup or just a simple [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) will all do the trick.)

Comment: Not sure if i understand.  `$letters = str_replace(array(1,2,3,4), array("a", "b", "c", "d"), $numbers);`

Answer (score 39):

It is very easy:

```
<?php
$row = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

echo "
<h2>question</h2>
<p>".chr(64 + $row[0])."</p>
<h2>answer</h2>
<p>".chr(64 + $row[1])."</p>";
```

Test it: http://3v4l.org/uojsK

Comment: This must be checked as the Right answer

Comment: charcode 65 is the capital A, if you are looking for the small one, start with 97

Answer (score 12):

you can define an array first:

```
$letters = array_combine(range(1,26), range('a', 'z'));
//now just use:
echo $letters[$row[1]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the alphabet array and use the numbers to get the right letter by index (num-1)

```
$letters = range('a','z');
$num = 3;
var_dump($letters[$num-1]);//"c"
```

i.e.

```
$letters = range('a','z');
echo "
<h2>question</h2>
<p>".$letters[$row[0]-1]."</p>
<h2>answer</h2>
<p>".$letters[$row[1]-1]."</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
///  the $row is the array you can get from db
$row = array(1,2,3,4,5);
// Here you can add your option up-to z
$alpha = range('A','E');
$i = 0;
///  Instead of foreach loop you can run while loop
foreach($row as $rows){
echo $alpha[($row[$i]-1)].'<br/>'; 
$i++;
}
?>
```